# NPM build failing with Webpack 5

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, polyfills

About a day or 2 ago, I ran my NPM build, but it suddenly gave the error that the polyfill is not provided by default anymore with Webpack 5. I was able to fix a lot of the errors, but it keeps failing.

I get the following errors:

[image]

These are just a few of them.

I'm using laravel-mix@6.0.13 in this build with the following webpack.mix.js file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('mix-tailwindcss');

 mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: require.resolve('browserify-fs'),
            path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
            "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
            "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
            "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
            "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "constants": require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
        }
    }
})
mix.options({ legacyNodePolyfills: false });

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .tailwind('./tailwind.config.js')

mix.sass('resources/scss/admin.scss', 'public/css')
```

My packages.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "mix-tailwindcss": "^1.3.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.12",
        "sass-loader": "10.*",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "buefy": "^0.9.6",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "mix-tailwindcss": "^1.3.0",
        "query-string": "^7.0.0",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-it-bigger": "^0.2.2"
    }
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I installed a fresh Laravel 8 instance, used your package.json and webpack.mix.js file, created blank files for scss/app.scss and scss/admin.scss as well as a default tailwind.config.js file. It all compiled successfully. It seems like at the beginning you are having issues with jest-worker but it isn't in your package.json. Maybe try: npm i jest-worker. Try that first and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I solved it. (solution in my anwser)

Answer (score 3):

Solved it!

I added the the `NodePolyfillPlugin` plugin to my webpack config. I added `browserify-fs` to `resolve.fallback.fs` like this.

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin") 

mix.webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
        ],
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                fs: require.resolve('browserify-fs'),
            }
        }
    })
```

After this the build kept failing, i finally figured out that for some reason i had `import {vue} from 'laravel-mix'` in my app.js . this was giving als the errors. After removing this it ran succesfully!